# How to get listview items both visible and invisible child values

Tags: android, listview

This loop return only visible position values.However I need the values of child items that are invisible.

```
for (int i = 0; i < material_issue_list.getCount(); i++) {

        View layout = materialIssueAdapter.getViewByPositio(i, material_issue_list);

                LinearLayout listItem = (LinearLayout) materialIssueAdapter.getViewByPositio(i, material_issue_list);

                String batchSTR = ((AutoCompleteTextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.batch_AutoComplete)).getText().toString();
                String qtySTR = ((EditText) listItem.findViewById(R.id.issue_qty_ETD)).getText().toString();}
```

My full adapter class,Some one help me suggest to get the correct output.My problem I'm getting null values from the views that are invisible.
Only the visible values are being updated to arraylist.
Thanks in advance.

```
public class IssueMaterialAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
public static ArrayList Dummylist;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
public Resources res;
public static ArrayList<BatchNav> batchNavs_Arr;
static ArrayList<String> batch_Arr;
public static ArrayList<String> batch_data;
public static ArrayList<String> issue_qty;
LinkedHashSet<String> hashSet;
public static ArrayList<BatchModel> batchModels = new ArrayList<BatchModel>();

public static HashMap<ViewHolder, String> batch_map;
public static HashMap<ViewHolder, String> qty_map;
HashMap<String, String> mValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
ArrayList<SaveDataModel> saveDataModels;


public IssueMaterialAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList dummy) {

    activity = a;
    Dummylist = dummy;

    loadBatch();
    this.batch_map = new HashMap<>();


    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    if (Dummylist.size() <= 0)
        return 1;
    return Dummylist.size();
}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.material_issue_details_list, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.batch = (AutoCompleteTextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.batch_AutoComplete);
        holder.issue = (EditText) vi.findViewById(R.id.issue_qty_ET);
        holder.material_descrption = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.material_desc);
        holder.unit_issue = (EditText) vi.findViewById(R.id.unit_issue_ET);
        holder.matnr = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.matnr);
        holder.prdgrp = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.prod_grp);
        vi.setTag(holder);

        batch_map.put(holder, "");


        FilterWithSpaceAdapter<String> farmer_co_no_adapter = new FilterWithSpaceAdapter<String>(activity,
                R.layout.custom_items, batch_Arr);
        holder.batch.setAdapter(farmer_co_no_adapter);
        holder.batch.setThreshold(1);
        vi.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
    }

    if (Dummylist.size() == AgriDistributionActivity.get_materials.size()) {

        holder.material_descrption.setText(AgriDistributionActivity.get_materials.get(position));
        holder.matnr.setText(AgriDistributionActivity.get_matnr.get(position));
        holder.prdgrp.setText(AgriDistributionActivity.selected_prdgrp.get(position));

    }




    try {
        if (saveDataArr.size() > 0) {

            holder.batch.setText(saveDataArr.get(position).getBatch());
            holder.issue.setText(saveDataArr.get(position).getQty());
            holder.unit_issue.setText(saveDataArr.get(position).getQty_uom());


        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }


    return vi;
}


public static class ViewHolder {

    public EditText issue, unit_issue;
    public AutoCompleteTextView batch;
    public TextView material_descrption, matnr,prdgrp;


}

private void loadBatch() {
    batch_Arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    batchNavs_Arr = new ArrayList<BatchNav>();
    hashSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();


    BatchNavEntityCollection batchNavEntityCollection = BatchNavEntityCollection.getInstance();
    batchNavs_Arr = batchNavEntityCollection.getBatchOutVal();
    for (int i = 0; i < batchNavs_Arr.size(); i++) {
        String batch = batchNavs_Arr.get(i).getCharg();
        batch_Arr.add(batch);
        hashSet.addAll(batch_Arr);
        batch_Arr.clear();
        batch_Arr.addAll(hashSet);


    }
}


public View getViewByPositio(int position, ListView listView) {
    final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

    if (position < firstListItemPosition || position > lastListItemPosition) {
        return listView.getAdapter().getView(position, null, listView);
    } else {
        final int childIndex = position - firstListItemPosition;
        return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `This loop return only visible position values` ? Of what?

Comment: What are you trying to do ? those views are gone for memory management, if you need data you have the List<Item> saved in your adapter

Comment: @greenapps return the visible values of editext and autocompletetextview

Comment: @yanivtwin Im trying get all the values present in a listview both visible and invisivle view,on a button click

Comment: you don't really need the views to get it , in the adapter you have the List with the data of all the list , use that to get the data

Comment: add your full adapter for more help

Comment: added @yanivtwin

Comment: this is just the getView , i need to see the whole class

Comment: @yanivtwin Posted

Answer (score 0):

You have saveDataArr list which holds all your data.
You can add a getter if you want to do it from an activity , add something like this to your adapter :

```
private SaveDataModelsendLog(int position) {
    return saveDataArr(position); 
}
```

That should do the trick , having said all that you should also look at the difference between static and non-static variables ,

it seems like you have to many of them , 
Enjoy.